# youtube api LiveBroadcasts response 200 but no livechatid

Tags: python, api, google-api, youtube

I am attempting to create a youtube chatbot. But I have found an error.

URL: https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/liveBroadcasts?part=snippet&id=

```json
{
  "kind": "youtube#liveBroadcastResponse",
  "etag": "MCWOUfwZBAquq7ZfmyosHKnzRFA",
  "pageInfo": {
    "totalResults": 0,
    "resultsPerPage": 5
  },
  "items": []
}
```

but it doesn't contain livechatid.

```
return data['items'][0]['snippet']['liveChatId']
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: show minimal working code. How did you send it? Did you use `POST` ?

Comment: yes. and it solved because i don't have permission for that livestream.